# Cloudflare DNS not hiding IP address?

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, dns, cloudflare

I want to setup and use Cloudflare DNS on my Windows 8.1 PC to hide my IP Address.

I changed the IPv4 properties from Adapter Settings to `1.1.1.1` and `1.0.0.1`
[image]

I also flushed the DNS resolver cache using the command:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

When I checked on this  [Cloudflare site](https://1.1.1.1/help?&_ga=2.76167901.95141802.1602821448-673336749.1602821448#eyJpc0NmIjoiWWVzIiwiaXNEb3QiOiJObyIsImlzRG9oIjoiTm8iLCJyZXNvbHZlcklwLTEuMS4xLjEiOiJZZXMiLCJyZXNvbHZlcklwLTEuMC4wLjEiOiJZZXMiLCJyZXNvbHZlcklwLTI2MDY6NDcwMDo0NzAwOjoxMTExIjoiWWVzIiwicmVzb2x2ZXJJcC0yNjA2OjQ3MDA6NDcwMDo6MTAwMSI6IlllcyIsImRhdGFjZW50ZXJMb2NhdGlvbiI6IllZWiIsImlzcE5hbWUiOiJDbG91ZGZsYXJlIiwiaXNwQXNuIjoiMTMzMzUifQ==), it shows that I am connected to their Network.

[image]

But the problem is that when I checked on google [ Just searched for Whats my ip] and a few other websites, my original ip address was perfectly visble.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think it's supposed to hide your ip

Comment: As others explained, this is not to provide any hiding. You just use Cloudflare's DNS servers to resolve IPs of remote hosts you're connecting to. The IP protocol passes your (source) IP address in the packets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of DNS as like a phone book…

You look up Dr Smith, 9 Acacia Gardens & see the corresponding phone number.
You ring Dr Smith - he knows who's calling because your number shows up on his phone.

That's all DNS does. It takes a name - [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com) - & looks up the number [IP address] for you to call. When you call it, you are calling from your own number [IP address]. No masking or hiding is provided.

If you want to hide, you need a VPN.

BTW, under normal circumstances, your own ISP's DNS ought to be faster & just as accurate.

Answer (score 1):

As others explained, this is not to provide any hiding. You just use Cloudflare's DNS servers to resolve IPs of remote hosts you're connecting to. The IP protocol passes your (source) IP address in the packets.

I use Cloudflare's DNS because it allows me to leverage "secure" DNS as in, for instance, "DNS over HTTP":
[image]

This is useful to hide the hostnames you're connecting to from 3rd parties like ISPs analyzing your traffic.